# Regex with 3-4 digits and two letters that can be anywhere in the string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to validate barcodes that always have 3-4 digits and 2 letters that can be anywhere in the string. I have checked various solutions but nothing works as I would expect. The problem is that letters and numbers can be anywhere in the string.

Examples:

```
23BD9  = correct
AS5879 = correct
12AA87 = correct
A879A  = correct
2A45D9 = correct

ASE125 = incorrect
12F589 = incorrect
12456  = incorrect
ABCDE  = incorrect
12AA   = incorrect
```

I tried

[A-Z + 0-9]{5,6}

[0-9]{2}[A-Z + 0-9]{3,4}

And many others, but unfortunately it works differently than it should

Comment: Please use https://regex101.com and https://regexr.com/. Also please choose _one_ target language.

Comment: Please show what you've tried already. We're definitly not here to give you the ready-to-copy solution

Comment: Why do you even need a regex? There seems to be no real pattern here, but instead just a number of certain characters.

Comment: It also seems to me that this cannot be handled by regex

Comment: FYI `[A-Z + 0-9]` checks for (uppercase) letters and digits, but also for a space and a `+`. You mean `[A-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex for this:

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){3,4}[a-zA-Z]*$)(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]*$).{5,6}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bAzaaL/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){3,4}[a-zA-Z]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires three or four repetitions of zero or more letters followed with a digit, and then zero or more letters till the end of string (=i.e. this requires 3-4 digits in an alphanumeric string)
- `(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires two repetitions of zero or more digits followed with a letter, and then zero or more digits till the end of string (=i.e. this requires 2 digits in an alphanumeric string)
- `.{5,6}` - five or six chars (the restriction to only allow letters and digits is already done in the lookaheads, but you may also replace `.` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` here)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Codegolfing it: `^(?=.{5,6}$)[0-9]*(?:[A-Za-z][0-9]*){2}$`

Answer (score 3):

A regex isn't well-suited for this task. I'd recommend LINQ, but you can also do this with a traditional for-loop if you need a more performant solution (it would be a micro-optimization, though).

```cs
var str = "23BD9";
int numbers = str.Count(x => char.IsNumber(x));

bool valid = (numbers == 3 || numbers == 4) &&
             (str.Count(x => char.IsLetter(x)) == 2);
```

You can drop the extra variable, but you'll need to re-calculate the same expression two times:

```cs
var str = "23BD9";

bool valid = (str.Count(x => char.IsNumber(x)) == 3 || str.Count(x => char.IsNumber(x)) == 4) &&
              str.Count(x => char.IsLetter(x)) == 2;
```

Starting with C# 9.0, you can write this more elegantly without the need for an extra variable:

```cs
var str = "23BD9";

bool valid = (str.Count(x => char.IsNumber(x)) is 3 or 4) && 
              str.Count(x => char.IsLetter(x)) == 2;
```

In addition, if you want to add another criteria in order to check if the string doesn't contain any non-alphanumeric characters, simply add this condition:

```
!str.Any(x => !(char.IsNumber(x) || char.IsLetter(x)))
```